# How to find an option tag with a specific value using jQuery

Tags: jquery, find, selected

I'm trying to set an option with a specific value as selected (using jQuery). I've got a string:

```
var data = '<select><option value="1">A</option><option value="2">B</option><option value="3">C</option></select>';
```

Now I'm trying to find the option tag with value=2 and set it as selected

```
$(data).find('option[value=2]').attr('selected','selected');
```

It's not working. I also tried:

```
$(data).find('option').each(function(){
if($(this).val()==2){
    $(this).attr('selected','selected');
}
});
```

which did not work either. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your code works fine, but of course you need to append it to the DOM to see the result. Here I used the [`appendTo()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) method.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/cqhGH/

```
 // --v---------------make sure the DOM is loaded
$(function() {
    var data = '<select><option value="1">A</option><option value="2">B</option><option value="3">C</option></select>';

    $(data).appendTo('body').find('option[value=2]').attr('selected','selected');
});
```

Though an easier way is to use the [`val()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/cqhGH/1/

```
$(function() {
    var data = '<select><option value="1">A</option><option value="2">B</option><option value="3">C</option></select>';

    $(data).appendTo('body').val(2);
});
```